# Changing 'Add to cart' button text and relink for some specific products

Tags: customization, shortcode, linking

I want to make custom button for some products in place of add to cart button on shop page and set dynamic relinking to some other page. So I made a checkbox at the product page and if that checkbox is enabled then the custom button with different link will be visible to that product. here is the code for checkbox:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wdm_add_meta_box' );
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wdm_add_customize_enable_metabox' );
function wdm_add_customize_enable_metabox() {
    add_meta_box(
        'Checkbox_metabox',
        'Check if you want to enable customization button',
        'wdm_enable_callback',
        'product',
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}

function wdm_enable_callback( $product ) {
    $custom = get_post_custom( $product -> ID );
    if( isset($custom[ "_wcm_custom_design_checkbox" ][0] ) ) {
        $meta_box_check = $custom[ "_wcm_custom_design_checkbox" ][0];
    }
    else {
        $meta_box_check = FALSE;
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Enable design panel at frontend?</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="wcm_enable_checkbox" id="wcm_enable_checkbox" <?php if ( $meta_box_check == true ) { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'wdm_save_meta_check_box_data', 10,2 );
function wdm_save_meta_check_box_data( $post_id, $product ){
    if ( $product -> post_type == 'product' ) {
        if ( isset($_POST["wcm_enable_checkbox"] ) && $_POST["wcm_enable_checkbox"] ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wcm_custom_design_checkbox', $_POST["wcm_enable_checkbox"] );
        }
        else {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wcm_custom_design_checkbox', '');
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine. I used this code into theme `add_to_cart` loop and here my only problem is how to get custom `add_to_cart_url()` for custom links and how to change the `add_to_cart_text()` text to whatever I want.

Here are the changes I made to `add_to_cart.php`:

```
global $product, $post;
$hasCustomization =  get_post_meta( $post -> ID, '_wcm_custom_design_checkbox', true );

if ( $hasCustomization == 'on' ) {
    echo apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
        sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="add_to_cart %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product -> add_to_cart_url() ),//Here i want my own urls
            esc_attr( $product->id ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            $product->is_purchasable() ? '' : '',//own css for custom text to show
            esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )// Custom Text
        ),
        $product
    );
}

else{
    echo apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
        sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="add_to_cart %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product -> add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( $product -> id ),
            esc_attr( $product -> get_sku() ),
            $product -> is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            esc_attr( $product -> product_type ),
            esc_html( $product -> add_to_cart_text() )
        ),
        $product
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is this _Product_ page coming from, WooCommerce?

Comment: Yes the add_to_cart.php page is from woocommerce

Comment: It's not advice to edit the plugin's files because if there was an update your custom changes are overwritten. Also are you getting an error?

Comment: No i am not getting any error the code is working properly but its just that when the button is clicked it adds the product to the cart instead of opening the product page...so i am not able to get to how to custom link it...n thankx for the advice i totally forgot dat :p

Comment: I think it's better to hook in the filter `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` than edit or override template like you did. can you `vardump` the `$hasCustomization` var and check its value, in addition, remove the `apply_filter` in `yes` condition

Comment: where can i find  "woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link"  hook and yes i have done vardump to $hasCustomization var and its returning the correct values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Ashish's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/101657/ashish-pariyani) answer that's been posted, below is the update code for clarification with the correct answer by switching `add_to_cart_url()` to `get_permalink()`:

```
global $product, $post;
$hasCustomization =  get_post_meta( $post -> ID, '_wcm_custom_design_checkbox', true );

if ( $hasCustomization == 'on' ) {
    echo apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
        sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="add_to_cart %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product -> get_permalink() ),
            esc_attr( $product->id ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            $product->is_purchasable() ? '' : '',to show
            esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )// Custom Text
        ),
        $product
    );
}

else{
    echo apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
        sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="add_to_cart %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product -> add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( $product -> id ),
            esc_attr( $product -> get_sku() ),
            $product -> is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            esc_attr( $product -> product_type ),
            esc_html( $product -> add_to_cart_text() )
        ),
        $product
    );
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it to work with just changing "add_to_cart_url()" to "get_permalink()" inside if statement. By doing this it gets the page url and links it to custom button. 
Thankx all for support :)